# Помогите сделать задание с помощью flex

Tags: html, css, flexbox

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
всего должно быть три колонки одинаковой ширины при
любой ширине браузера;
при изменении ширины браузера ширина колонок тоже
должна изменяться.

Comment: это 33% называется

Comment: @teran, `33.33%` ;D

Answer (score 2):

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.grid__inner {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  max-width: 1140px;
  margin: -15px;
}

.grid__column {
  width: 33.333%;
  padding: 15px;
}

.card {
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid">
  <div class="grid__inner">
    <div class="grid__column">
      <div class="card" style="background-color: red; height: 300px"></div>
      <div class="card" style="background-color: yellow; height: 150px"></div>
      <div class="card" style="background-color: pink; height: 150px"></div>
    </div>
    
    <div class="grid__column">
      <div class="card" style="background-color: red; height: 200px"></div>
      <div class="card" style="background-color: yellow; height: 300px"></div>
      <div class="card" style="background-color: pink; height: 150px"></div>
    </div>
    
    <div class="grid__column">
      <div class="card" style="background-color: red; height: 250px"></div>
      <div class="card" style="background-color: yellow; height: 350px"></div>
      <div class="card" style="background-color: pink; height: 200px"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```